# Combining three mysql statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to simplify some mysql.  I have three selects and three tables:

```
SELECT pageid FROM thepage WHERE DATE(createdate)='2011-11-09' ORDER BY createdate DESC

SELECT urlid FROM themix WHERE pageid=...

SELECT link FROM theurl WHERE urlid=...
```

Given a createdate, it gets all pageid's, then goes to a second table and gets all urlid's for those pageid's then gets the links for all those urlid's.  I'm using while loops right now, but suspect there is a way to join them all into one.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: right, you already said.. you want to JOIN the tables

Comment: Looks like a simple SQL JOIN operation to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT p.pageid
     , u.link
FROM thepage p INNER JOIN themix m
    ON p.pageid = m.pageid
INNER JOIN theurl u
    ON m.urlid = u.urlid
WHERE DATE(p.createdate) = '2011-11-09'
ORDER BY p.createdate DESC
```

should do the trick i think. If you want only unique URLs, use this:

```
SELECT u.link
FROM thepage p 
  INNER JOIN themix m
    ON p.pageid = m.pageid
  INNER JOIN theurl u
    ON m.urlid = u.urlid
WHERE DATE(p.createdate) = '2011-11-09'
GROUP BY m.urlid
ORDER BY MIN(p.createdate) DESC
```

---

**Sidenotes**

```
WHERE DATE(p.createdate) = '2011-11-09'
```

will have to scan the whole `page` table and call the `DATE()` function for every row. You have two options to make it faster:

Change the `createdate` to `DATE` (from `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, that it is now) and use:

```
WHERE p.createdate = '2011-11-09'
```

or keep it as it is and use:

```
WHERE p.createdate >= '2011-11-09'
  AND p.createdate < '2011-11-10'
```

---

Table and column names are better without prefixes or suffixes like the `the` you have. Isn't this cleaner and clearer (even without the aliases)?

```
SELECT url.link
FROM page
  INNER JOIN mix
    ON page.pageid = mix.pageid
  INNER JOIN url
    ON mix.urlid = url.urlid
WHERE DATE(page.createdate) = '2011-11-09'
ORDER BY page.createdate DESC
```

Comment: Seems to work!  thanks, is there any particular trick you use to simplify the mental process?  any tips?

Comment: Not really, just look at what i did, and at some point you just get the idea (that was my experience atleast).

Comment: @dragon112 even better for dates (IMO), convert your physical date, `2011-11-09`, to time stamp, and use that to compare.

Comment: @David19801: If a URL is related to many Pages, then you'll get it many times.

Comment: @table names, sometimes mysql stops working because the simple table names are used for internal things, so I make complex names...still can't seem to get it working to pull just unique urls...It's getting all 600 out...

Comment: reply to self: to get unique values, change first line to 
SELECT distinct url.link

Answer (score 2):

you already received some feedback in the comments to your post. you should really learn about the different types of sql joins

what you want should be achieved by something like this:

```
SELECT 
    theurl.link  
FROM 
    thepage  
LEFT JOIN 
    themix 
ON 
    thepage.pageid = urlid.pageid 
LEFT JOIN 
    theurl 
ON 
    theurl.urlid = themix.urlid 
WHERE 
    DATE(thepage.createdate)='2011-11-09' 
ORDER BY 
    thepage.createdate DESC
```

you should use the answers you got here as a starting point for your study on sql

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT link from theurl where (select urlid from themix where (select
>   pageid from thepage where WHERE DATE(createdate)='2011-11-09' ORDER BY
>   createdate DESC))

OR

> SELECT link from theurl as tu , themix as tm, thepage as tp where
>   tu.id=tm.urlid and tm.pageid=tp.id and DATE(createdate)='2011-11-09'
>   ORDER BY
>   createdate DESC

Any way it will give result.

Comment: Can he uses where? Or must he uses IN?

Comment: First one: Error, subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the 3 queries into 1 and use the IN-expression to search for multiple id's.